# the setColorFilter doesn't work in onTabSelected event in android 5

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabs, android-tablelayout

I have Tablayout that works with ViewPager. I used custom tab for tabs. But the problem with that is the Colorfilter doesn't work on onTabSelected event in android 5 but it works in andrid 4.4 very well.
This is my custom layout for tab:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textColor="@color/custom_selector"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tabText" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is what i did on for selected tab icon:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
         tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "IRANSans_Bold.ttf");

        tabCustomization();
        /*changeTabsFont();*/
        setupTabIcons();
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    }

    private void tabCustomization() {
        viewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);

        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        adapter.addFragment(new MenuFragment(), "menu");

        adapter.addFragment(new AddressFragment(), "Address");
        adapter.addFragment(new SearchFragment(), "Search");
        adapter.addFragment(new IssueFragment(), "Issue");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);


            tab.setCustomView(adapter.getTabView(tabLayout,i));

        }


        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
        int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
        Log.i("TabChild",String.valueOf(tabsCount));


// Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view

    }
    public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    }
    private void setupTabIcons() {

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);


        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){


            @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });
    }


    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }
        public View getTabView(TabLayout tabLayout,int position) {
            // Given you have a custom layout in `res/layout/custom_tab.xml` with a TextView and ImageView

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, tabLayout, false);
            TextView textView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabText);

            textView.setText(getPageTitle(position));
            textView.setTypeface(tf);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(tabIcons[position]);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }

    }
```

Comment: tried to `mutate()` your `Drawable`?

Comment: @pskink what do u mean, how can i mutate it, is there a tutorial

Comment: read `Drawable` class documentation

Comment: @pskink i used  tab.getIcon().mutate().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN); but it also doesn't work anymore

Comment: I also code change the color of imageview using color filter in android 5 i got imageview id and then setcolorfilter like this imageView.setColorFilter(R.color.color_tab_gray); in onclick event, it works in android 5 of

Comment: what type of `Drawable` is `tab.getIcon()`? is it `android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable`?

Comment: i looked in tablayout.java, it is a method that return Drawable, that exactly the code that i share above but i added mutate method after getIcon

Comment: just use `Log.d(TAG, "getIcon " + tab.getIcon());`, what do you see?

Comment: I saw this getIcon android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@307d55f

Comment: this http://pastebin.com/5hQDwaZ6 just works fine on android 4.4 and 5.0 versions

Comment: @pskink i tried that but it doesn't work in android 5 and even android 6, it works on android 4.4 without mutate()

Comment: i tested on v5.0 so i know it works ok, what "design" library are you using? i tested with 25.0.0

Comment: @pskink do u use custom tablayout, because in regular mode i don't have any problem with that and it works ok but when i use custom tab layout the setcolorfilter doesn't work anymore

Comment: this is layout i used (res/layout/tabs.xml) http://pastebin.com/xVs2JzeH, what custom tab layout do you mean?

Comment: the case that i'm working with is that i did custom tab like this http://pastebin.com/xUk9gBvi and inflate it in getTabView method like this http://pastebin.com/0645Wrdd

Comment: so use `tab.getCustomView()`

Comment: @pskink you mean using getcustomView instead of getTabView

Comment: yes, i mean `tab.getCustomView()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on my research, The setColorFilter doesn't have conflict with android 5 and the problem was the ways i chose. What i have done for selected and unselected is to getcustomview base on what @pskink said in the above comment and because it is linearlayout, I got the child view and set the colorfilter directly to imageview that is in my custom layout:

```
public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

}
private void setupTabIcons() {

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){


        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            /*tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);*/
            linearLayout=(LinearLayout)tab.getCustomView();
            ImageView v=(ImageView)linearLayout.getChildAt(0);
            v.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a8a8a8"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

             linearLayout=(LinearLayout)tab.getCustomView();
            ImageView v=(ImageView)linearLayout.getChildAt(0);
            v.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will do your work

```
  private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_play));
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_timer));
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_increasing_stocks_graphic));

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {


        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(utility.getColor(R.color.blue), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(utility.getColor(R.color.light_grey), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(utility.getColor(R.color.blue), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
    });

}
```